# Java switch (use values in a case calculated in another case)

Tags: java

I'm making a program that has menus and I'm using switch to navigate between the menus.

I have something like this:

```
switch (pick) {
    case 1:
    // Here the program ask the user to input some data related with students (lets say
    // name and dob). Student is a class and the students data is stored in 1 array of
    // students. If I do:
    // for (Student item: students){
    //          if (item != null){
    //              System.out.println(item);
    //          }     
    // }
    // It will print the name and dob of all the students inserted because I've created
    // a toString() method that returns the name and dob of the students

    case 2:
    // On case 2 at some point I will need to print the array created on the case
    // above. If I do again:
    // for (Student item: students){
    //          if (item != null){
    //              System.out.println(item);
    //          }     
    // }
    // It says that students variable might have not been initialized.
```

Question:

If a variable is created in one case it's values can't be used in another case?
What I was trying to do was first enter in case 1 and input the values and then, in case 2 be able to use some of the values defined in case 1.

If this can't be done, please point me in the right direction.

Please keep in mind that I've started to learn java only a few weeks.

favolas

Comment: You said "question one:", is there also a "question two"?

Comment: @java lava My bad. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variables before the switch and you'll be able to use them in all cases

```
int var1;

switch(number) {
  case 1:
    var1 = 2;
    break;
  case 2:
    var2 += 3;
    break;
  ...
```

Comment: P.S. don't forget to add the break statements at the end of each case because statements in case labels are executed in sequence until a break is encountered. see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Thanks. Forget about that and already know that have to put break.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there are curly brackets, you have what is known as a different scope.

If you create variables in there, they are lost when you leave that scope.

If you create the variable BEFORE, you can use it.

```
int subMenu = 0;

switch(...){

...
subMenu = 1;

}

if (subMenu == 1 ){
 ....
}
```

Will work even when you leave the switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to declare (ie: int a = 2) a variable in case 1 and then use it also in case 2 you will get the error message: "Variable is already defined...". That explains why you can't do that, the compiler has to know you have declared a variable before you use it.

If you declare all the variables before the switch-statement you will be fine. An example:

```
int var;
swith(...){
  case 1:
    var ++;
    break;
  case 2:
    var +=10;
    break;
}
```